# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined from API fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

```
const [address, setAddress] = useState("")
const [neighborhood, setNeighborhood] = useState("")
const [city, setCity] = useState("")
const [state, setState] = useState("")

const searchZIP = async(zip) => {
    zip = zip.replace(/\D/g, "")
    const data = await fetch(`http://viacep.com.br/ws/${zip}/json/`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .catch(() => {
            setAddress("--")
            setNeighborhood("--")
            setCity("--")
            setState("--")
        })
    const { logradouro="--", bairro="--", localidade="--", uf="--" } = data
```

> The error is ocurring when it tries to read this last line (reading: 'logradouro') for a invalid ZIP input even though I assign "--" as a default value.

```
    setAddress(logradouro)
    setNeighborhood(bairro)
    setCity(localidade)
    setState(uf)
```

[image]

Comment: You are making two mistakes: 1. in your `.then` handler you assume that the json is what you think it is without checking and 2. in your `.catch` handler you don't return anything, so `data` is `undefined`. You can't destructure `undefined`, even if you provide defaults in the destructuring.

Comment: post the actual error, there should be relevant info in it

Comment: @JaredSmith thank you! Doing .catch(data => data="") solved it!

Comment: @GheistLycis You'll want `.catch(() => ({}))` or `.catch(err => { console.error(err); return {}; })`. Don't return `data=""`.